# including fetched data in DOM element via angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, fetch

So i am trying to convert my app from jQuery to angularjs.

I want to create a dynamically shown box which shows data fetched from a mySQl database, based on user input.

My PHP script returns a JSON.

I set up my `<div>` and an `<input>` field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="testActivator">

<div class="Container" ng-show="Activator.length" ng-controller="ContainerCtrl">
        <p>{{fetchData(testActivator)}}</p>
</div>
```

And i create my controller:

```
function ContainerCtrl($scope,$http){

$scope.item = [{}];

$scope.fetchData = function($input){

    $http.post("../sys/core/fetchPacking.php",{
        'val': $input
    }).success(function(data,status){
        $scope.item.push(data.key);
    });

    return $scope.item;

}

$scope.hide = function(){
    return false;
}

}
```

Now, the following and questions came up:

- When i start the script by giving input to the `<input>`, it will produce something that looks like an infinite loop to me: the returned data will be passed in the box over and over again. How do i prevent this and why is it?
- Instead of the correct value, the script returns `null`. Where is my fault?

p.s. issue #1 throws also up another question: How do i watch my returned values. Until today, i would have parsed it to the console via `console.log()`. But as this runs in a loop, that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

First of all your testActivator needs to be inside of the same scope as ContainerCtrl.

I suppose you want to call fetchData when the input value changes? Then you should use the ng-change directive.

It does not make sense to call the fetchData function inside of the expression. The fetchData function should make the request and put the result data into a variable in the scope.
Inside of the expression you can then show this fetched data:

```
<div class="Container" ng-controller="ContainerCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="testActivator" ng-change="fetchData(testActivator)">

    <div>
        <p ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your controller should look something like that:

```
function ContainerCtrl($scope,$http) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.fetchData = function(input){
        $http.post("../sys/core/fetchPacking.php",{
            'val': input
        }).success(function(data,status){
            $scope.items.push(data.key);
        });
    }
}
```

I think you should work through the AngularJS Tutorial:
http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

You need to "watch" `testActivator` for changes in your controller...

```
$scope.$watch('testActivator', function (testActivator) {
    $scope.fetchData(testActivator);
});

$scope.fetchData = function (testActivator) {
    $http.post("../sys/core/fetchPacking.php", {'val': testActivator})
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.item.push(data.key);
        });
};
```

And the `testActivator` input needs to be within the scope of `ContainerCtrl`...

```
<div class="Container" ng-show="Activator.length" ng-controller="ContainerCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="testActivator">

    <p ng-repeat="item in items">{{item | json}}</p>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you can use angular's "dot rule" to resolve visibility issues between parent and child scopes:

- http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY

Basically, just change `testActivator` to something like `foo.testActivator`.